# Ruby on Rails - Use date to trigger action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an object that has an end date which is created using the callback `after_create`.

I'm wondering where the best place is to include the logic which would trigger an action when the object expires. `(Time.now.in_time_zone > Object.end_date)`

I'd like to create a method that checks whether an object has the attribute `repeat` as true or false. If it's true and the current date is passed the end date of the object, it should add 7 days to the end date of the object.

I have a method which checks whether the object is still valid but it's a boolean and I use it multiple times in the view so if I include it there, it gets executed multiple times before the view is even updated and I end up adding too many days to the end date.

Is it possible to have an action in your view file which is called automatically when the page loads if it falls under a certain condition? I'm guessing this is bad practice because I've read a few articles about avoiding too much logic in your view files.

I'm sure there are many ways of doing this so could you please let me know what methods you've used to overcome this?

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Can you add the code for the *method which checks whether the object is still valid ..* ? I would like to understand the problem a bit better.

Comment: I don't really understand the desired logic behind `repeat` vs `end_date`. Naively, should it not be that `end_date` **is not set** if `object.repeat == true`? Rather than trying to hack some "extension" logic into a controller action? Extending the `end_date` by 7 days doesn't sound like the right solution??!

Comment: You *could* even implement it has: "if `end_date == nil`, then it's a repeated event" - thus even eliminating the need for a flag?

Comment: @TomLord - The reason for `repeat` and `end_date` is that I would like to give the user the option whether to have the object expire or continually refresh once expired. The end date is used as a deadline to complete a task. @PeterAndersen - The code is pretty straight forward, it's a couple of conditions in a `.where()` method with `.exists?` chained at the end. `if self.OBJECT.where("period = ? AND end_date > ?", 1, Time.now.in_time_zone).exists?`

Comment: @Nathan *"continually refresh once expired"* -- Surely you can see the irony in this phrase? What's the point in having an expiry, if it never expires? Being given the *option* to *renew* the expiration is one thing, but your current design doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I mean... For example, what happens if you view a record 8 days after it expires? By your logic above, it should be "automatically extended" to expire yesterday!! (And *only* when you view it?! So records are expired until someone looks at them, then are instantly renewed? This makes no sense to me.)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a Controller **before_action**, which would be called as you mentioned before the page loads.

Adapting the example in the Rails docs at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

```
class MyObjectsController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :object_expire, only: [:show]

  private

  def object_expire
    # perform some logic here
    if @my_object.expired?
      @expired_result = @my_object.do_repeat
    end  
  end
end
```

**EDIT** - limit before_action to show actions only